# duplicate React components in the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js (without Redux or other State management library)

I have a single page app with two screens:
"MainL list" AND "My List"
When a user selects an item from the "Main list", then this item is being added to "My List".

The problem that I have is that when a user selects an item or two from the Main List and then switches to "My List", then he sometimes will see same items replicated twice.

It seems to be an issue with an array mutation of wrong usage of key IDs.
The items in both of the screens are represented by an array. So one array of items for the Main List and one array for the My List

To toggle the visibility of the screens, I use the following code:

```
this.state.screenLocation === "MainList" ? (
  this.state.cardsMainList.map((value, index) => (
    <ItemCard key={index} card={value} location={"MainList"} />
  ))
) : this.state.screenLocation === "MyList" ? (
  this.state.cardsMyList.map((value, index) => (
    <ItemCard
      key={index + 100000}
      card={value}
      location={"MyList"}
      added={true}
    />
  ))
) : (
  <div> Error: Wrong Screen Location </div>
);
```

When I switch to My List screen, I get the items info from the database and then change the array of the My List:

```
let cards = [];

//then an API call to the server to retrieve items from the DB
// ........
//then the following:

cards = response.data.results[0];

this.setState({ cardsMyList: cards });
```

Do I mutate the array wrongly? Do I use

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this.setState({...this.state, cardsMyList: cards});

Comment: What are the contents of `cardsMyList` when you see this problem?

Comment: @Roy.B, thank you. I tried. didn't help

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, if a user selects two items from the MainList, then the content of cardsMyList can have either two or four items. (items can be repeated, but they are not always repeated. so hard to catch what's the issue ) seems like some issue with the State

Comment: can you update the code and tell about cardsMainList and cardsMyList?

Comment: _This doesn't look like an issue with state to me as `cardsMyList` is populated from the result of an external service call._ "When a user selects an item from the "Main list", then this item is being added to "My List", you need to provide more context has to how the selected item is added to "My List" in your question